# What is equivalent mmap in C++ for linux?

Tags: linux, c++, mmap

What is equivalent `mmap` into C++?

I have code like below

```c
LCDdata = mmap(NULL, iFrameBufferSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, 0);
```

Where `LCDdata` is `unsigned char` type `pointer`, `iFrameBufferSize` is `int` type and `fb_fd` is `static int` type.

When I compile it by use of arm `g++` tool chain it give me error as below

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'unsigned char*' [-fpermissive]
```

So how can I use any equivalent type function instead of `mmap`?

Which header file I should include? And how this new line's syntax will become?

Comment: Did you try typecasting it? `LCDdata = (unsigned char*) mmap(NULL...`

Comment: Your problem isn't mmap, your problem is you are using it incorrectly (the type of your arguments is wrong).

Comment: @steeldriver's suggestion is better (using `static_cast`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ equivalent is `auto LCDdata = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mmap(...`

In C++ we prefer to define out variables only when we initialize them, and because of that we often don't need to specify the type anymore. Here, we don't need to repeat `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Just to add to the answer. mmap returns a void*. C has a more relaxed type system and allows implicit casting of a void* to any other pointer type. C++ is more strictly typed and will only allow explicit casting of a void* to another pointer type.

Comment: @doron C doesn't have a more relaxed type system; it has basically the same type system but it has implicit conversion from `void *`.

Comment: @JayminD: That's probably because you declared `LCDdata` earlier; you can probably remove that earlier declaration.

Answer (score 3):

C allows `void*` to be assigned to pointers of any type without a cast.  C++ does not.  C programmers have complained about this for ages (`malloc` being the most common complaint), but it's not likely to change.

The solution is to add the cast.  If the source needs to be compilable as C, use a C-style cast:

```
LCDdata = (unsigned char*)mmap(...);
```

Otherwise use a C++ cast

```
LCDdata = static_cast<unsigned char*>(mmap(...));
```

If you want to do something more drastic, you could look into [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file).  That would give you RAII.

Comment: "compilable as C" isn't a thing (well - it shouldn't be, but sadly it is in a few minds). Either you are writing C or you're writing C++.

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, C and C++ are separate languages.  I'm no fan of Lua's "clean C" name for the intersection of the two ( http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html , first paragraph).  But there has been a lot of effort to make a lot of valid C code also valid C++ code.  And there are good reasons to run the same source file through a C compiler sometimes and a C++ compiler other times.  I don't know if the original poster wants to do that, so I bring up how to (and alternatives if he doesn't want to maintain C compatibility).

Comment: @M.M - you are, respectfully, factually incorrect.  A subset of C code can be compiled using a C++ compiler and vice versa, and I'm sure you know this already.  I understand that you have personal preferences, but the compiler doesn't care about our (i.e., neither yours, nor my) personal preferences.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug A subset of C code can be run using a Python interpreter as well .  By "isn't a thing", I mean that it isn't a desirable goal outside of code golfing . People trying to write code that is valid in two separate languages are usually confused about what they are doing (in my opinion)